# how to send mail with the link attached

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
        body += "" & HtmlNewLine.ToString & ""
        body += "Please enter Quotation."
        body += "AFTER ENTER QUATATION MY LINK SHOULD BE THERE"
        body += "" & HtmlNewLine.ToString & ""
        body += "" & HtmlNewLine.ToString & ""
        body += "Enquiry Details :"
        body += "" & HtmlNewLine.ToString & ""
        body += "" & HtmlNewLine.ToString & ""
        For Each grvRow1 In grdVProdDetAdd.Rows
            body += "" & CType(grvRow1.FindControl("lblSubGrp"), Label).Text & " "
            body += "" & HtmlNewLine.ToString & ""
```

I want to display it as a link in the mail but instead of that it is displaying like word. please help

Comment: I HAVE TRIED USING HREF BUT NOT WORKING..ANY OTHER WAY PLEASE

Comment: Have you set IsBodyHtml to true?

Comment: no..i don't understand what u r telling can u please explain me with code

Comment: Set IsBodytml property of your MailMessage object to true.

Comment: i didnt use Isbody in my code please check my code above.

Comment: Are you using MailMessage object in your code?

Comment: no am using Dim objmail As New sendEmail in code

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<a>` tag to insert text as link:

```
<a href=" + "\"" + linkvalue + "\"" + ">" + linkName + "</a>
```

Comment: <a href= "+"/""+"http://101/Module/Purchase/Qutation/QuotationAgainstEnquiry.aspx"+""/"+"> "+click+"</a>        erroe in href ..href should have ">" element...please check

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a `sendEmail` class. If it's an imported reference you should tell us where to get it so that we can help you. Here's the answer for the MailMessage class ('mail' is the defined MailMessage variable):

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = True
mail.Body = "<a href="http://www.blabla.com/">Visit our website today!</a>"
```